# TypeError: unhashable type despite using body-format: json in uri: task

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-awx

If I add a body to a uri: task the task fails with "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: unhashable type"

If I remove the body: then the Web service returns an error (because it needs the body!) but at least it gets as far as the webservice!

This is the task:

```
  - name: create new RE if RE doesn't exist
    uri:
      url: https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/v1.3/runtimes/remote-engines
      method: POST
      headers:
        Authorization: Basic {{talend_personal_access_token}}
        Accept: application/json
      status-code: 201
      body-format: json
      body:
        name: "{{RE_name}}"
    register: new_RE_response
    when: check_response.json[0].id is undefined
```

This is the output:

```
{
    "status": -1,
    "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_uri_payload_nEptqB/ansible_uri_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 1359, in fetch_url\n    unix_socket=unix_socket)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_uri_payload_nEptqB/ansible_uri_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 1257, in open_url\n    use_gssapi=use_gssapi, unix_socket=unix_socket)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_uri_payload_nEptqB/ansible_uri_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 1163, in open\n    r = urllib_request.urlopen(*urlopen_args)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py\", line 154, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py\", line 431, in open\n    response = self._open(req, data)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py\", line 449, in _open\n    '_open', req)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py\", line 409, in _call_chain\n    result = func(*args)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_uri_payload_nEptqB/ansible_uri_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 356, in https_open\n    return self.do_open(CustomHTTPSConnection, req)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py\", line 1211, in do_open\n    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py\", line 1056, in request\n    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py\", line 1090, in _send_request\n    self.endheaders(body)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py\", line 1052, in endheaders\n    self._send_output(message_body)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py\", line 894, in _send_output\n    self.send(message_body)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py\", line 866, in send\n    self.sock.sendall(data)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py\", line 744, in sendall\n    v = self.send(data[count:])\nTypeError: unhashable type\n",
    "url": "https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/v1.3/runtimes/remote-engines",
    "changed": false,
    "elapsed": 1,
    "content": "",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "directory_mode": null,
            "force": false,
            "remote_src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "follow": false,
            "owner": null,
            "body_format": "raw",
            "body-format": "json",
            "client_key": null,
            "group": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic <censored>"
            },
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "setype": null,
            "content": null,
            "serole": null,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "return_content": false,
            "client_cert": null,
            "body": {
                "name": "RHEL_X.X.X.X_AZGLGBNEVTA30_PRODUCTION_C4E"
            },
            "timeout": 30,
            "src": null,
            "dest": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "force_basic_auth": true,
            "removes": null,
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "regexp": null,
            "status-code": 201,
            "url_password": null,
            "url": "https://api.eu.cloud.talend.com/tmc/v1.3/runtimes/remote-engines",
            "validate_certs": true,
            "seuser": null,
            "method": "POST",
            "creates": null,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "mode": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null
        }
    },
    "redirected": false,
    "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: unhashable type",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

This is the Ansible version:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/jason_ho/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

This is running through AWX 9.1.1

Is it a bug or something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As noted below, you need to change 'status-code: 201' to 'status_code: 201'.  Having that parameter spelled incorrectly would use the defaults - and "200" is the default as you mentioned below.

When you do fix this, does the playbook work as expected now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  The correct variable is `status_code`, not `status-code`.

(An "underline" and not a "dash": https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html)

Comment: I ended up re-typing the whole task out from scratch to get it working and (checking what it is now) you are 100% spot on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using status code 201 and expecting status code to be 200 success. Remove status code if you are expecting 200 success response.
Second of all, use `return_content: true` if you are sending a POST request.

For more info. check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#uri-interacts-with-webservices

Comment: No, I'm expecting 201 to be a success (as per the documentation of the web service), I don't know why the error message is reporting that it is looking for 200, presumably it's hardcoded into the error message.

Comment: From the link: ````if the reported Content-type is "application/json", then the JSON is always loaded into a key called json in the dictionary results.````

Comment: and

````When [body_format] set to json or form-urlencoded, encodes the body argument, if needed, and **automatically sets the Content-Type header accordingly.**````